# Kendo Grid renders properly but does not display json data

Tags: ajax, json, kendo-ui, grid

I have been having a tough time with grids lately, mostly getting them to display properly formatted JSON data that is being fetched from a webservice (which has been checked in VS2013, and JSONLint), if a second set of eyes could please have a look at my solution and tell me whats lacking? I am going bananas!

function SetTelerikGrid() {

```
// prepare the data object and consume data from web service,...
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "http://localhost:38312/SDMSService.svc/GetProductPositionsByLocation/0544",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (ProductData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // populate kendo location grid by data from successful ajax call,...
        $("#LocationProductsGrid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: ProductData, // solution here was: **JSON.parse(LocationData)**
                        schema: {
                            model: {                                    
                                fields: {
                                    Date: { type: "string" },
                                    ProductCode: { type: "string" },
                                    StoreNum: { type: "string" },                                        
                                    ProductQty: { type: "int" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20
                    },
                    height: 550,
                    scrollable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        input: true,
                        numeric: false
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { field: "Date", title: "Date", width: "130px" },
                        { field: "ProductCode", title: "Product Code", width: "130px" },
                        { field: "StoreNum", title: "Store Number", width: "130px" },                            
                        { field: "ProductQty", title: "Product Qty", width: "130px" }
                    ]
                });

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the 'ProductData' field - although in perfect JSON format - still required to be parsed as JSON in the datasource configuration, like so,...

Data: JSON.parse(ProductData)

Comment: Glad that you solved it out. But for binding the grid you can use the datasource "read" method. It wont require explicit parsing or anything. Just a suggestion. :)

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-dataSource

Answer (score 4):

There is a breaking change in ***ASP.NET Core***, related to how the `JSON serializer`

works
You can probably mitigate this by adding a json option like this:

**1:**
change

```
services.AddMvc();
```

to

services

```
.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

OR

**2:**

```
public IActionResult Read()
{
  // Override serializer settings per-action
  return Json(
     MyModel,
     new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }
  );
}
```

refrences :
http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-2016-2-630-preview---data-not-displayed#qlHR6zhqhkqLZWuHfdUDpA

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1856#issuecomment-229874309

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1856#issuecomment-230450923